# Avoid '-' as user-input by applying replace() with suitable regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a javascript function that replaces all "-" found. But it will just replace the "-" entered from the keyboard Num. introduce the other takes as an alpha numeric character I think. I know this because through this [link](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes), the character code is different. My code: http://jsfiddle.net/cqrjjzn8/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('input').keyup(function(e) {

        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if(code == 109 || code == 189) { //Enter keycode
           //Do something
            var valor = $(this).val();
            $(this).val(valor.replace(/[-]/g, ''))
            //$(this).val(valor.replace(/[-]/w, '')) // MY "-" alpha numeric
        }
    });
```

my problem is that I am not able to find the correct regex to do this.

Note: this problem does not happen in all keyboards, so this problem does not happen at all pc's

Comment: Perhaps, you will be interested in [Dash category](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pd/list.htm)? Perhaps, this regex will work for you: `/[\u002D\u058A\u05BE\u1400\u1806\u2010-\u2015\u2E17\u2E1A\u2E3A\u2E3B\u2E40\u301C\u3030\u30A0\uFE31\uFE32\uFE58\uFE63\uFF0D]/g`.

Comment: Use `keypress` event instead of `keyup` and don't let user input `-`, then you do not need to replace it.

Comment: dont work @stribizhev.

Comment: @MithleshKumar, how? can you do a little example plz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$('input').keypress(function(e) {

 var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        console.log(code)
 if(code == 45) { //Enter keycode       
    return false
 }
});
```

Here you can test this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cqrjjzn8/7/)

Please check all key code [here](http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html), as we have different key code for different event type.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: That eliminates the problem "before it occurs", great solution! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the `.change()` portion of your code. The following (just the `keyup()` part) works fine for me:

```
$('input').keyup(function(e) {
    var valor = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(valor.replace(/[-]/g, ''))
});
```

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/t9myunhv/

or for those of us who are even lazier when it comes to typing code:

```
$('input').keyup(function(e) {
  with ($(this)) val(val().replace(/-/g, ''));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t9myunhv/2/

Comment: in my chrome, I then can not move the cursor, always gets the last character

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var valor = $(this).val();
valor = valor.replace(/-/g, '');
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: The `-` on its own does not have any special meaning in a regexp, therefore the \ is entirely optional. `/-/` works too.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').on('keyup', function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(code == 173) {
        //Enter keycode
        //Do something
        var valor = $(this).val();
        $(this).val(valor.replace(/[-]/g, ''))
   }  
});
```

check this out http://jsfiddle.net/emnity/cqrjjzn8/9/

Comment: in my mozilla the problem continues